# What is the actual duration of a Snackbar with LENGTH_LONG

Tags: android, androidx, lint, android-snackbar

Since I've migrated my Android Project to AndroidX i am receiving the following **lint** error:

```
Error: Must be one of: Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG [WrongConstant]
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, message, sticky ? Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE : 4500
```

So instead of defining a custom duration (4500ms), I am now using `Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG`.
Since i am implementing some time-based operation that depends on how long the snackbar is visible, I need to know the actual duration of `Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG` in milliseconds. How do I find out that value?

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar#length_long) are not really helpful here:

> Show the Snackbar for a short period of time.

Comment: I think you can also use setDuration with a custom value in milliseconds.

Comment: You are right, its still possible to use custom milliseconds with Snackbar.setDuration(). They've only restricted using a custom value in Snackbar.make(...).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

After some fishing in the source code you will find these constants in the `SnackbarManager`:

```
private static final int SHORT_DURATION_MS = 1500;
private static final int LONG_DURATION_MS = 2750;
```

So to answer your question the actual duration for the long length is 2750 milliseconds.

---

Class `com.google.android.material.snackbar.SnackbarManager`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually tried to look it up in the source code but couldn't find the value somehow.

Comment: This is actually very useful since I kept getting a lint error for using the Snackbar length constants in Gradle 3.6.4.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by jbarat, but here's it in the source code as asked by a user. Could not reply in the thread, and so posting it as an answer.
[2.75 Seconds](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1f6ebe9e7bb224cc3adc60de3944adfb9e8eaacb/lib/java/com/google/android/material/snackbar/SnackbarManager.java#L32)